# SYMFONY3 PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_intl.dll

Tags: php7

I have installed SYMFONY 3 and I have this error : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll'

, I uncomment the php.intl extension in the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

DLL is a dynamic link library file format used for holding multiple codes and procedures for Windows programs. DLL files were created so that multiple programs could use their information at the same time, aiding memory conservation.

Please comment the line you've uncommented because DLL is for Windows. Ubuntu doesn't find files with extension *.dll.